# Error When SignOut Users - invertase React Native Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to signOut users from My App, but I'm having this message from console.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_auth.firebase.auth.currentUser.signOut')
```

following documentation (https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/auth/reference/module#signOut) I made a function like this

```
async function LogoutUser() {
    firebase.auth.currentUser.signOut();
  }
```

but nothing happens with user Account. Please, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`signOut` is function of auth. try below code

```
 firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(){
        console.log('Signed Out');
    },function(error){

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async function LogoutUser() {
    **await** firebase.auth.currentUser.signOut();
}
```

Don't forget the use of await

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await